# Javascript mute/unmute video using image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

For some reason, it's just not working.. What am I doing wrong?
I want to be able to mute and unmute the video using an image, which is changing whether the video is muted or not.

```js
 function mute() {
            var video = document.getElementById("bgvid");
         if (!video.muted) {
             document.getElementById('muteicon').src = "Images/muteicon.png";
            video.muted;
         }     else {
             document.getElementById('muteicon').src = "Images/soundicon.png";
             video.muted == false;
             }

        }
```

```css
video#bgvid {
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 60px;

            width: 1280px; height: 720px;


            background-size: cover;

        }
        video { display: block; }
```

```html
<video autoplay loop id="bgvid">
        <source src="newyork.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <br><br>
    <img alt="mute icon" src="Images/soundicon.png" id="muteicon" onclick="mute()">
    <script>
      </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the `muted` property to `true` when you are trying to mute the video.

```
if (!video.muted) {
    document.getElementById('muteicon').src = "Images/muteicon.png";
    video.muted = true; // you need to assign this value to true
} else { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the [assign(`=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment) operator instead of the [equality(`==`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality) operator:

```
function mute() {
    var video = document.getElementById("bgvid");

    if (!video.muted) {
        document.getElementById('muteicon').src = "Images/muteicon.png";
        // video.muted <- not assigned to true
        video.muted = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('muteicon').src = "Images/soundicon.png";
        // video.muted == false <- wrong use of equality operator
        video.muted = false;
    }
}
```

And you can't tell the API to set a property to `true` just by calling it as you made:

```
video.muted
```

You have to assign the property to a value:

```
video.muted = true
```